# CSV file from txt using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt file with info inside of it, separated for every deal with \n symbol.

```
DEAL: 896
CITY: New York
MARKET: Manhattan
PRICE: $9,750,000
ASSET TYPE: Rental Building
SF: 8,004
PPSF: $1,218
DATE: 11/01/2017
```

Is there any way to make a csv (or another) table with headers, specified like CITY, MARKET, etc. with pandas or csv module? All the info from specific title should go into corresponding header

Comment: check pandas.pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to navigate around using `:` as a delimiter:

```
import pandas as pd
new_temp = open('temp.txt', 'w') # writing data to a new file changing the first delimiter only
with open('fun.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(':', '|', 1) # only replace first instance of : to use this as delimiter for pandas
        new_temp.write(line)
new_temp.close()

df = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', delimiter='|', header=None)
df = df.set_index([0]).T
df.to_csv('./new_transposed_df.csv', index=False)
```

Will make a csv with the left column as headers and the right column as data without changing colons in the second column. It will write out a temp file called temp.txt which you can remove after you run the program.

Comment: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 10, saw 3`

Comment: this works only if your data is as you posted it. I copied your example into a text file and ran this so if there is some deviation from what you posted it may not work. I also don't know what line 10 is in your code as what I posted is 3 lines.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Yeah, there are like 700 of such deals, some with different headers

Comment: It appears that one (or some) of the deals in the file have a `:` in column 1 or column 2 (for example if you had one that said `Time: 9:00 am`, 3 which would create 3 columns instead of 2 and just fill the 2nd column with `9` and the 3rd column with `00 am` for those :P. Cleaning up your data is half the battle!

Comment: You right, I have a LINK title, and after that comes https://, any way to avoid taking : as delimiter after https?

Comment: I'm cooking something up that may work if you don't have any `|` characters

Comment: As far as I know there shouldn't be any :P

Comment: It works really nice! :) But it makes a csv with 2 rows and inserts new deals to the right. Is it possible to insert new deals without titles below in corresponding columns?

Comment: You right, thanks for everything :) Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas to input it and then transform/pivot your table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep=':',header=None)

df = df.set_index(0).T
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''
DEAL: 896
CITY: New York
MARKET: Manhattan
PRICE: $9,750,000
ASSET TYPE: Rental Building
SF: 8,004
PPSF: $1,218
DATE: 11/01/2017
'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data),sep=':',header=None)

print(df.set_index(0).T)
```

Results:[image]

Comment: you edited your code to be the exact same as mine, haha.

Comment: ;) I did not know there was another answer. I am on mobile ;) After writing the answer I went and test it on online Jupyter Notebook, tryjupyter, and ended updating my code. Great minds thinks the same